# JSON decode shows "Array"

Tags: php, json, curl, encode

This part:

```
$response_2 = json_decode($response_2, true);
```

...of the code below is echoed literally as "Array" in the browser. If I remove the part, the full $response_2 is echoed in browser in JSON-format just like in this example: https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-list-users-playlists/

How come?

```
<?php

$url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token';
$method = 'POST';

$credentials = "hidden:hidden";

$headers = array(
        "Accept: */*",
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($credentials));
$data = 'grant_type=client_credentials';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$response = json_decode($response, true);

$token = $response['access_token'];

echo "My token is: " . $token;

$headers_2 = array(
        "Accept: */*",
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        ('Authorization: Bearer ' . $token));

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/wizzler/playlists');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers_2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response_2 = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$response_2 = json_decode($response_2, true);

echo $response_2;

?>
```

Comment: `json_decode()` returns an array. You can't echo an array. Use `print_r()` or `var_dump()` to inspect the contents. And then echo a specific element, like so: `echo $response_2['foo'];`.

Comment: Appreciated! I went with `print_r ($response_2);` and it worked great.

Comment: Cool. Note, however, that `print_r()`  is just for debugging; it is not meant to be used in actual code. @Rawland

Comment: You'd need to iterate over the array with a `foreach` loop.

Comment: In the next step I want to this though:
`foreach($response_2['items'] as $item) {echo 'Title: ' . $item['external_urls'] . '<br />';
    echo 'Brand: ' . $item['owner']['external_urls'] . '<br />';
}`
If replace "echo" with "print_r" nothing happens. Am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: Try `foreach($response_2 as $item){...}` may work, but I'm not a JSON guy. See if Explosion can help or post a new question.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work. I'll post a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `echo` on an array, it just prints out the literal string `Array`.  This is just a quirk of PHP.

If you want to print out the contents of the array, you can use `print_r()` or `var_dump()`.

However it seems like what you actually want to do is print the JSON, which is the string.  `$response_2` is already a string, so print it out.

Comment: It should be noted that this applies to objects as well (in reference to the OP's [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24539756/problems-with-parsing-json-objects#24539756))...